# Vertical motion within one column

Tags: cursor-movement

How can one move vertically, staying in the same column (implicitly adding spaces), regardless of line lengths? (If the next line is shorter than the current, <kbd>j</kbd> will move the cursor to the last character of the next line.) This would be useful when adding comments.

Comment: *Maybe* `set virtualedit=all` (but read about it first: `:h virtualedit`)

Answer (score 5):

You can consider `set ve=insert` if you just want to do virtual edit in insert mode.

`set ve=all` if you want to do virtual editing in all modes. This may break some macro or plugin (if the plugin doesn't check the `ve` option).

[`:h 've'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ve%27) to know more about `virtualedit` option.

You can add a mapping, easily setting the `ve` option to `all` and back for your requirements, just like toggling line numbers.